# WSO2 3.0.0 databases for production

Tags: wso2-api-manager

What are the recommendations for the CARBONDB and METRICSDB in production?

In the documentation: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/SetupAndInstall/SettingUpDatabases/overview/
CARBONDB and METRICSDB seems related to the instance internal settings and not shared between instances.

So in a production deployment, is it safe to let them managed by h2 or is it better to use a real DB (ex: MariaDB)? If a real DB should be used, does it means that in a distributed deployment we have to create plenty of carbon and metrics schemas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CARBONDB stores the server related information and those are recoverable if something happens to the carbon database. That's why having H2 is fine for production.

Metrics are now disabled by default in APIM v3.0.0 and due to that, there is no use of Metrics database. So having H2 database for metrics is fine.